# Generating POST data for Django TestCase and test.client

Tags: django, testing, testcase

I have some somewhat complex, dynamic client side forms that keep changing. So I want to write a set of tests that are independent of the client side. I am using django.test.TestCase to accomplish this (rather than webtest or selenium)

I want to test some update functions. Django test client requires the POST data to be a dict. The problem is my form page actually has two forms plus a formset. Manually creating the POST dict from the model instances seems painful, especially since we know Django goes through the same process when it is putting initial data in a form during normal (non-testing) operations.

I tried doing a GET first and then grabbing the data from the response. But that pretty ended up being pretty convoluted; no better than just building the dict from the instances.

Does anyone know an elegant way to do this?